# Wordpad opening an .xls file in html format?

Tags: excel

I got an .xls file from my friend. When I try to open that in excel it is opening fine. But when I try to open the same file in Wordpad it was showing the file contents using table tags like following:

```
<table border=1 cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="580">
<style>

        <!--table

        .xl31

        {mso-style-parent:style0;

        mso-number-format:"\@";

        text-align:left;

        border-top:none;

        border-right:.5pt solid black;

        border-bottom:.5pt solid black;

        border-left:none;

        white-space:normal;}

        --> 
        <tr><td> By _______________ </td><td colspan=2 > By ____________ </td></tr>

        <tr><td>(Authorized  Signature) </td><td colspan=2 >  (Authorized  Signature)</td></tr>

        </table></th></tr> 
</table>
```

But when I created an excel file using microsoft office-2003 and open it in Wordpad it is showing some junk data. 
Could someone help me to find what could be the difference between these files?

Comment: Not programming related. "Computer use" != "programming". Voted to migrate to SuperUser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's common practice in many web apps out there to "cheat" a little and create Excel downloads by formatting data as an HTML table and sending it with a header describing the content as an Excel file.  Excel will still render the data OK, thought it might complain that what was in the download didn't look like a real Excel file.

That's likely how your friend got that file.  If you try it with an Excel file you created from Excel its either going to be binary (xls) or a zipped up set of XML files (2007+) so its not going to have any content you can read directly using Wordpad.